# Creating window layout in PyGTK 2

Tags: python, layout, python-2.7, pygtk

I am trying to create a simple aplication in Python 2.7 using PyGTK 2. The main window will contain several widgets (like buttons and a tree view). I know that I can place these widgets in window using options like **gtk.Box**, **gtk.Fixed** or **gtk.Layout**.

Which of these would be better to use? Are there any other possibilities?

Thanks.

Comment: I completely depend on what layout you want, but in general gtk works with packing boxes rather than specifying fixed positions so gtk.HBox, gtk.VBox and gtk.Table are the wdigets I'd prefer to use. Do draw on a paper or something how you wish to organize your layout in terms of these...